# Migrating from Struts1 to Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts-1

I am migrating an application from Struts 1 to Struts 2. I have encountered the following code snippet. Please let me know how to replace the code snippet in Struts 2.

```java
protected ActionForward getActionForward(FilterContext ctx, String key, boolean redirect) {
    HashMap filterForwards = ctx.getFilterForwards();
    String forwardPage = (String)filterForwards.get(key);
    if(forwardPage == null)
        return null;
    return new ActionForward(forwardPage, redirect);
}
```

And another code snippet is like this:-

```java
protected void setError(HttpServletRequest req, String msg) {
        ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
        errors.add("exception", new ActionMessage(MSG_KEY, msg));
        req.setAttribute(Globals.ERROR_KEY, errors);
    }
```

Should I replace the above code with `addActionError(msg)`?

Comment: can you post your full code. by this code we can't guess what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well it is difficult to post the entire code. But in the 1st case, the function is for page redirection. In the 2nd case the code is for setting global action error. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Struts 1 you should return `ActionForward` from the `execute` method. Struts 2 returns a result code of type `String`. So the code where `ActionForward` is expected should be replaced with result code. The action result should be configured to the action the same way like you configure forwards in Struts 1.

Create two result configs: one is `redirectAction` result type, and another `dispatcher` result type. Like this

```xml
<result name="redirect" type="redirectAction">${forwardPage}</result>
<result>${forwardPage}</result>
```

The code should be replace with

```java
private String forwardPage; 

public String getForwardPage() { return forwardPage; }

public void setForwardPage(String forwardPage) {
  this.forwardPage = forwardPage;
} 

protected String getActionForward(FilterContext ctx, String key, boolean redirect) {
    HashMap filterForwards = ctx.getFilterForwards();
    String forwardPage = (String)filterForwards.get(key);
    if(forwardPage == null)
        return NONE;
    if (redirect) {
       setForwardPage(forwardPage);
       return "redirect";
    } else {
       setForwardPage(forwardPage)
       return SUCCESS; 
    }
}
```

The errors are provided by the `ActionSupport` class that your action should inherit. Then you can use the code

```java
protected void setError(String msg) {
    addActionError(getText("exception", new Object[]{msg}));
}
```

In the JSP you can display errors with

```xml
<s:actionerror/>
```